# Unused state fields in react eslint error

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

New to react, I'm using a class component and getting **unused state fields error for filteredItems**

Don't understand why is it unused when i'm already using them in my datatable component

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filterText: '',
      filteredItems: '', //Initalize state
    };
  }

 // ... ommitted other parts

  render() {
    const result = arr1.map(item => item[1]);
    // this.filteredItems = result;
    if (result) {
      this.setState({
        filteredItems: result,  //Trying to setState with result array. Getting unused state fields error
      });
    }

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <DataTable
          columns={columns}
          data={this.filteredItems} // Trying to Using this.filteredItems

    // ... ommitted other parts
```

Comment: `this.filteredItems` doesn't point to your state value. It should be changed to `this.state.filteredItems`

Comment: I'm getting this now >> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: That is due to `setState` is being called inside the `render` method. You could move the `arr1.map(item => item[1])` line directly into the `data` prop of `DataTable` as a quick fix (and also remove the `setState` call).

Answer (score 1):

The error means exactly what it says: Your state has field[s] that are not *read* anywhere.
If you initialize `state={ attributeA: '', attributeB: ''}` and never read `attributeA`, then you will get that error.

Your example has a lot of missing code. However, in your example you do not use the `state.filterText` and that is where the error comes from.

Keep in mind that the error you are getting is not from javascsript or React themselves, but from eslint, which is a tool used to hightlight wrong practices (such as declaring state attributes and not using them).